# Are there any universally accepted or non-Abrahamic based books in history that have mentions of longevity of prophets?

Tags: religion, book

Reading from [here](http://blog.adw.org/2017/02/noah-really-live-950/) and [Genesis 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen%205&version=ESV) we see that there are mentions of longevity among prophets:

Adam – 930

Seth – 912

Enosh – 905

Jared – 962

Methuselah – 969

Noah – 950

Shem – 600

Eber – 464

Abraham – 175

Moses – 120

My question is are there any **other** historical books (a book that has nothing to do with Abrahamic religions) that mention any of these ages? Basically what I'm asking was there any non-religious, secular book written that cites these ages? OR perhaps a book written by Abrahamic followers that is still somewhat *universally* accepted?

I personally consider the old and new testament as (partially history) books that can be referenced but consider that out of the scope of the question.

**I'm not asking whether what they've mentioned is accurate. I'm only asking if it's even mentioned at all...**

Comment: Do these people have any historic significance outside of the Abrahamic religions? That is, is there any reason that secular scribes would have made note of their (supposed) ages?

Comment: @KillingTime Today atheists speak about Jesus, Moses, Mohammad etc. I find it unlikely that their non-followers wouldn't be speaking about prominent figures surrounding them. So yes they have historic significance.

Comment: How prominent do you think any of those people were outside of their followers? Glossing over that two of them are said to be directly responsible for all humans alive at some point.

Comment: With the possible exception of Moses, none of these are regarded as 'prophets' by Judeo-Christian tradition. The term 'patriarchs' is used sometimes.

Comment: @Spencer Adam and Noah are not prophets?!

Comment: No, they're not, but I did misspeak about Abraham,  who according to readily available online sources is the first person referred to in the Bible as a "prophet".

Comment: @Spencer According to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/was-noah-a-prophet) it seems that Noah was a prophet

Comment: Most people consider these to be mythical figures with mythical attributes...

Comment: @sofageneral Can you back that up? Last I checked 4,200,000,000 believe in Christianity and Islam combined. Longevity of prophets/people is documented in these books.

Comment: @Honey show me the poll that says 100% of the faithful believe in the mythical numbers.    * I can play your games too *   In fact I am willing to posit most of the faithfuls can't even identify 1/2 the mythical figures on that list let a lone know how long they supposedly lived.  everyone knows Adam, Moses and Noah.  Some know about Abraham, but after that...    you will get a blank look from most of the faithfuls.

Comment: 2021: adam is a 'prophet' ? it seems discussed in comments but no edits made to post re this

Answer (score 4):

(Meta) Question 1: Is it possible that Human beings actually used to live that long?

**No, it is not**. The human body is not [designed with the capability of living beyond about 125](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_life_span#In_humans). We have ample archeological samples from actual burials in the Ancient era, and earlier, all of which confirm that people of that era lived much *shorter* lives than modern humans, not longer. [Life expectancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_expectancy#Variation_over_time) in the Ancient Era would have been around 30 years (vs 72 now).

(Actual) Question 2: Are there other ancient records that claim unreasonably long lifespans like the Bible does?

Yes there are. The [Sumerian King list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_King_List) shows Gilgamesh ruling for 128 years, and some lesser-known kings ruling for **tens of thousands** of years. I think the record-holder is [En-men-lu-ana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En-men-lu-ana), at 43,200 years. What these have in common with the Bible is that the further removed from the actual date that humans wrote that record, the longer a lifespan the writer attributes to them.

**So essentially, it appears that more mythological figures get ascribed longer lives**. The closer to living memory of when the record was taken, the more realistic their lifespan. This holds both for the Bible, the Sumerian King List, and other ancient king lists, *even though all of them were recorded at very different times*.

Comment: Abeit your answer is corret, I don't think OP actually asked "Question 1"

Comment: 1. wasn't ask if it's possible...that looks more like a comment on the question. 2. from the link you shared...there are some disputes on it, any reason you didn't include them? Some quotes from the life expectancy's  [external references](http://longevity-science.org/Biodemography.html): *"This conclusion is important, because it challenge the common belief in existence of a fixed maximal human life span."* +  Another [study](https://f1000research.com/articles/6-569/v1) disputed because of *simple coding errors and biased sampling* ie its debated 3. the last paragraph is more like an opinion.

Comment: @RMalke - Yes, it is true question 1 wasn't explicitly asked. However, I've had **more than one person** offline start to discuss 2 with me as a way to get to 1. If I *hadn't* addressed it, I could see this historical answer being used by someone (not necessarily the question author) for ahistorical purposes. I've had that happen to me before here, and I won't put up with having it happen again.

Comment: @Honey Question 1 needs considered however.  It is part of how a historical source is judged as being accepted as historically accurate or dismissed as mythology.  If a source contains things we know today to be impossible, then we can't accept it (at least those parts) as historically accurate. A Yale lecturer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdOlGUlqy2c&t=3136s) discusses these very apsects when considering  how or if we can use Homer as a source for information on pre-classical Greece.

Comment: I do not think but could be wrong that people, once beyond childhood, expected to live only to 30 but rather the well-known idea that childhood mortality contributed to a much shorter *average* lifespan. In ancient Rome, there were people who made it to 100 although probably fewer per capita. Perhaps there really was time when 30 was considered old but I don't know when that was. I realize that your link mentions that it is average life expectancy -- it does not rule out extreme old age at any time in history.

Comment: @Jeff Among the Comanche, life  expectancy into the 30's seems to have been a norm.  (Fehrenbach)  The unusual lived into later decades.

Comment: The curve is not flat.  Even with a life expectancy in the thirties, you'll still see people mostly dying at <10 and >50.  This is why when we read history, we see many prominent people living into their fifties and sixties even in societies where the life expectancy is low.  Roman offices had age requirements of the late thirties and early forties.  That implies a society where people "expected" to live that long.  Realize that with infant mortality rate of 50%, a "30 year life expectancy" means that the average person who reaches a year lives to 60.

Comment: For any interested in academic studies on longevity: In addition to [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38225/are-there-any-universally-accepted-or-non-abrahamic-based-books-in-history-that#comment97754_38227) comment, I've also found a [post from a Researcher into Biotechnology, Nanotechnology and Anti-Aging Medicine](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-that-in-100-years-time-the-average-human-life-expectancy-could-be-into-the-hundreds/answer/Johnty-Andersen?srid=PdV3) which says it's possible and not mystical. Though *this* answer's resources say it's mystical